# Typescript Testing Library jest.fn() toHaveBeenCalled() not working

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm writing Jest for the components to make sure that the functionality is working as expected. Not sure why I keep getting error that jest.fn() is not executed once. I have removed most of unnecessary code here

This is my mock repository

```
export class MockRepository extends DataRepository {
    async dataAccess(
        requestBody: dataDto,
        bucket: Bucket
      ): Promise<GetResult<{ id: number; data: number},null>> {
    
        const tdataAccess = {
          id: 1,
          data: 1
        };

        return dataAccess;
      }

    async createData(): Promise<void> {}
}
```

This is my testclass

```
beforeAll(async () => {
        module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [AppModule],
            controllers: [DataController],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: DataRepository,
                    useClass: MockRepository
                },
                DataService,
            ]
        }).compile()

        app = module.createNestApplication()
        await app.init()
        repository = module.get<DataRepository>(DataRepository)
    })

it('should test the /addData endpoint', async () => {
        const mockRepository = module.get(MockRepository)
        const checkDataAccessSpy = jest.spyOn(mockRepository, 'checkData')
        const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
            .post('/api/addData')
            .send(mockRequestBody)
        await expect(checkDataAccessSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
        await expect(mockRepository.createData).not.toBeCalled();

        expect(response.body).toEqual({ allowed: true })
    })
```

This is the error log

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      71 |                      .post('/api/addData')
      72 |                      .send(mockRequestBody)
    > 73 |              await expect(checkDataAccessSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
         |                                                 ^
      74 |              await expect(mockRepository.createData).not.toBeCalled();
      75 |
      76 |              expect(response.body).toEqual({ allowed: true })

      at Object.<anonymous> (modules/api/test/data.test.ts:73:38)
```

I have verified that mock repository dataAccess() can be executed.,by adding console.log("----") to it but I keep getting error as above.

Comment: With `useClass`, how do you know the test and the implementation are getting the same _instance_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe am passing mockRepositoy in the provider.i have tried botj useClass  and useValue. getting the same error

Comment: @arj can you add your code which you want to test?